# SoundCloud Widget API: How do I get LOAD_PROGRESS to work?

Tags: api, widget, soundcloud

I am using SoundCloud Widget API on Safari iOS12. 
Despite, many responses to the contrary I can get my audio to play automatically:

```
function playAudio(id){
    var player = SC.Widget('audio-' + id);
                player.bind(SC.Widget.Events.READY,function(){
        onSCPlayerReady(player);
    }
);
            player.bind(SC.Widget.Events.PLAY,function(event){
        onSCPlayerStateChange(event);
    }
);
                    player.bind(SC.Widget.Events.LOAD_PROGRESS, function(event) {
        onSCPlayerLoadProgress(event);
    }
);

}
```

The problem with LOAD_PROGRESS, is that it only gives me 2 readings. 0 & then 1, and nothing in between and I only get these readings using the PLAY event binding from event.loadProgress. I cannot get LOAD_PROGRESS to work on iOS12?

```
function onSCPlayerReady(player) {
    console.log("onSCPlayerReady(): player.play();");
    player.play();
}

function onSCPlayerStateChange(event) {
    console.log("onSCPlayerStateChange(): event.loadedProgress", event.loadedProgress);
}

function onSCPlayerLoadProgress(event) {
    console.log("onSCPlayerLoadProgress(): event", event);
}
```

I only get console output in 'onSCPlayerReady' and 'onSCPlayerStateChange', but not 'onSCPlayerLoadProgress'.

Does anyone know how I can get 'onSCPlayerLoadProgress' to respond?

The reason I want to use LOAD_PROGRESS, is because I want to set up a loading progress bar to let users know that something is happening before the audio plays?

Answer (score 0):

SC.Widget.Events.LOAD_PROGRESS gives only a status 0 = not buffering / 1 = buffering
SC.Widget.Events.PLAY_PROGRESS gives event.loadedProgress